# How to access data on a child component from state of parent component only by id

Tags: reactjs

I need to access the `value` attribute of each `<Square />` class after the `handleClick` event in order to display it on the `button` such as "`X`" in this case. whenever i try something like `{this.props.cell.value}` it throws an error even on `{this.props.cell[this.props.id].value}`.

(the code is unfinished so ill get on the logic of "X" or "O" later)

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      cell: [{id: 1,value: null},{id: 2,value: null},{id: 3,value: null},{  id: 4,value: null},{id: 5,value: null},{id: 6,value: null},{id: 7,value: null},  {id: 8,value: null},{id: 9,value: null}];
 }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick(x) {
    const cell = [...this.state.cell]
    cell[x].value = "X"
    return this.setState({ cell })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          <Table
            item={this.state.cell}
            handleClick={this.handleClick}
          />
        }
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Start Game</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Table extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="table">
        {this.props.item.map(a => (
          <Square
            key={a.id}
            id={a.id}
            handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Square extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="cell"
        onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.id)}
      >
        *{??????}*
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `Data` at `item={Data}`? Is it supposed to be `this.state.cell`?

Comment: yes sorry, i had that in another file but pasted it on the `cell` to not drag another file to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass another property with the value of the Square and then show it :) 
Like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      cell: [{id: 1,value: null},{id: 2,value: null},{id: 3,value: null},{ id: 4,value: null},{id: 5,value: null},{id: 6,value: null},{id: 7,value: null},{id: 8,value: null},{id: 9,value: null}]};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(x) {
    const cell = [...this.state.cell]
    cell[x-1].value = "X"
    return this.setState({ cell })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {
          <Table
            item={this.state.cell}
            handleClick={this.handleClick}
          />
        }
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Start Game</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="table">
        {this.props.item.map(a => (
          <Square
            key={a.id}
            id={a.id}
            value={a.value}
            handleClick={this.props.handleClick}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Square extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="cell"
        onClick={() => this.props.handleClick(this.props.id)}
      >
      {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

Note that I add each Square a property called `value` and passed it `value={a.value}`.

Then, in square, you can show it :) `{this.props.value}`

Plus, i changed the assignment in handleClick to this: `cell[x-1].value = "X"`, since the id starts from 1, but array's first item's index is 0.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now that i think of it i feel stupid how didnt i figure that out before. Thanks alot mate :)

Comment: @Dav if this answer is the correct one please mark it as such, so we know the question is resolved